# changing color of multiple logos every second

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make logos to change color every second with this transition

```
i{
  color: blue; 
  transition: color .5s;
}
```

i want to logos in `i class` to smoothly change color from white to red in loop

this is part of code of my website

```
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div id="aboutMe" class="text-center">
        <h1 class="text-4xl bg-blend-color border-l-green-500 font-thin text-white">igorekowo >_<</h1>
        <h1 id="typedText" class="text-lg drop-shadow-xl font-thin text-white">owo
        </h1>
        <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-spotify pt-4 text-3xl text-white/50 font-extralight cursor-pointer" style="font-size:36px; text-shadow: 0 0 0.10em rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://discordapp.com/users/..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-discord pt-4 text-3xl text-white/50 font-extralight cursor-pointer" style="font-size:36px; text-shadow: 0 0 0.10em rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://youtube.com/..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube pt-4 text-3xl text-white/50 font-extralight cursor-pointer" style="font-size:36px; text-shadow: 0 0 0.10em rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok pt-4 text-3xl text-white/50 font-extralight cursor-pointer" style="font-size:36px; text-shadow: 0 0 0.10em rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com/..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram pt-4 text-3xl text-white/50 font-extralight cursor-pointer" style="font-size:36px; text-shadow: 0 0 0.10em rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
        </a>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
      type(["(*≧ω≦*)", "i luv igorekowo :3", "meow ^_^"], typewriterElement,textIndex,charIndex,isDeleting, isLineVisible);
      updateTitle("kys.mom <3 ");
    </script>
    <script>
var colors = ['white', 'red'];
var active = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('i').style.color = colors[active];
    active++;
    if (active == colors.length) active = 0;
}, 1500);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i found code to change background color and remade it to change color of logos but it only change 1 logo, and i dont know how to make that it change all 5 logos

(this is the code that i remade)

```
    <script>
var colors = ['white', 'red'];
var active = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('i').style.color = colors[active];
    active++;
    if (active == colors.length) active = 0;
}, 1500);
    </script>
```

Comment: Use `querySelectotAll('i')` to get a collection of all elements you want and then iterate through them.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `document.querySelector` which returns the first element that it finds a match to.  Instead you need to use `document.querySelectorAll` which returns a list of ALL matching elements.

Do this to loop over your element matches. Note that I moved the selector to be OUTSIDE of the `setInterval` since there's no need to keep selecting the same elements every iteration. Just select them once, save to a variable, and then modify on each iteration

```js
const colors = ['white', 'red'];
let active = 0;
const iconElements = document.querySelectorAll('i');

setInterval(function(){
  iconElements.forEach(el => el.style.color = colors[active]);
  active++;
  if (active == colors.length) active = 0;
}, 1500);
```

Comment: thanks, and is it possible that first logo will turn red after a 1 second, second logo will turn red, and first logo will turn white, and do this until fifth logo, and do it in loop?

Comment: Yes, but you probably need a different question for that since that's entirely different.  Since you have the entire list of elements in the `iconElements` variable and you are looping though them, you have access to the index in that loop. You just need to keep track of which element is active just like you do with the index for the color array. `iconElements.forEach((el, i) => { el.style.color = i === activeEl ? 'red' : 'white;}); activeEl++; if(activeEl === iconElements.length) activeEl =0;`

Answer (score 0):

Put in this code in your script tag to change the colours of the logos in an interval:

```
var allLogos = document.querySelectorAll('i')    
    var currentLogoIndex = 0
    const interval = setInterval(function () {
        
        const colourLogo = (index, color) => {
            allLogos[index].style.color = color
        }

        // First Logo
        if(currentLogoIndex===0){
            colourLogo(allLogos.length - 1, "blue")
            colourLogo(currentLogoIndex, "red")
        }

        // Middle Logos
        else if(currentLogoIndex>0 && currentLogoIndex < allLogos.length - 1){
            colourLogo(currentLogoIndex, "red")
            colourLogo(currentLogoIndex - 1, "blue")
        }
        
        // Last logo
        else{
            colourLogo(currentLogoIndex, "red")
            colourLogo(currentLogoIndex - 1, "blue")
            currentLogoIndex = -1
        }
        currentLogoIndex++

        
    }, 1000);
```