# changing logos color

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make that first logo will turn red after a 1 second, second logo will turn red, and first logo will turn white, and do this until fifth logo, and do it in loop, here is code that i have for turning red all logos at the same time

```
const colors = ['white', 'red'];
let active = 0;
const iconElements = document.querySelectorAll('i');

setInterval(function(){
  iconElements.forEach(el => el.style.color = colors[active]);
  active++;
  if (active == colors.length) active = 0;
}, 1500);
```

and here is part of code of my website

```
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div id="aboutMe" class="text-center">
        <h1 class="text-4xl bg-blend-color border-l-green-500 font-thin text-white">igorekowo >_<</h1>
        <h1 id="typedText" class="text-lg drop-shadow-xl font-thin text-white">owo
        </h1>
        <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-spotify pt-4 text-3xl text-white/50 font-extralight cursor-pointer" style="font-size:36px; text-shadow: 0 0 0.10em rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://discordapp.com/users/..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-discord pt-4 text-3xl text-white/50 font-extralight cursor-pointer" style="font-size:36px; text-shadow: 0 0 0.10em rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://youtube.com/..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube pt-4 text-3xl text-white/50 font-extralight cursor-pointer" style="font-size:36px; text-shadow: 0 0 0.10em rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok pt-4 text-3xl text-white/50 font-extralight cursor-pointer" style="font-size:36px; text-shadow: 0 0 0.10em rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com/..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram pt-4 text-3xl text-white/50 font-extralight cursor-pointer" style="font-size:36px; text-shadow: 0 0 0.10em rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
        </a>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
      type(["(*≧ω≦*)", "i luv igorekowo :3", "meow ^_^"], typewriterElement,textIndex,charIndex,isDeleting, isLineVisible);
      updateTitle("kys.mom <3 ");
    </script>
    <script>
var colors = ['white', 'red'];
var active = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('i').style.color = colors[active];
    active++;
    if (active == colors.length) active = 0;
}, 1500);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a question about how to achieve your goal?

Comment: As-is, your code has several syntax errors that should be fixed.

Comment: yeah, I've been struggling with this for like 3 hours and still dont know how to do it

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: with writing code for changing colors of logos, as i said, i want to make that first logo will turn red after a 1 second, second logo will turn red, and first logo will turn white, and do this until fifth logo, and do it in loop, but i dont know how to make it, that's why im asking here for help me/write it for me, i made question 2 hours ago about similar problem so if you want to help, maybe you should check it ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77418584/changing-color-of-multiple-logos-every-second )

Comment: You gave a very generic "problem," but we aren't a code writing service, nor mindreaders. Which part of your code are you having problems with? Which pieces aren't working as expected? Have you checked your console for errors? What are the functions `type()` and `updateTitle()`?

Comment: Read about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you'll get more responses.

Comment: This, by any chance: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r0cLh1sk/? as others have said, though, you really need to clarify your expectations; you really should pay attention to @mykaft's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Do you mean this?

```
setInterval(function () {
  iconElements.forEach((el, index) => {
    el.style.color =
      colors[((active + iconElements.length - index) % iconElements.length == 0) % 2];
  });
  active++;
}, 1000);
```

I hope my answer can help you.

Good luck.

Comment: Am I right? .If my answer is false, please explain more detail.

Comment: this is not quite what I wanted, watch this video to help you understand what i want https://streamable.com/dzrn6t (its not accurate because i did it fast but i think you will understand), and if u want to check how it looks right now check https://rogusia.github.io/test.kys.mom/

Comment: so you mean 'streamable.com/dzrn6t' is right? or  'rogusia.github.io/test.kys.mom'  is right?

Comment: I changed my code and it works like video in 'streamable.com/dzrn6t'.    please copy and try again.

Comment: streamable.com/dzrn6t is what i want, and rogusia.github.io/test.kys.mom is what it looks right now (i dont want that)

Comment: I add captured video in my answer. just copy my code and replace old code.

Comment: I tried to help you.  I already changed my code 23mins ago, but you have old code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for (an alternating colour change, I put in Blue instead of white because it's more visible, but you can change the colour as needed):

```
<script>
    var allLogos = document.querySelectorAll('i')    
    var currentLogoIndex = 0
    const interval = setInterval(function () {
        // if last logo, stop and reset to blue
        if(currentLogoIndex==allLogos.length){            
            allLogos[currentLogoIndex - 1].style.color = "blue"
          //clearInterval(interval)
           currentLogoIndex=0
          return  
        } 
        // set current logo to red
        allLogos[currentLogoIndex].style.color = "red"
        // set previous logo to white (if it exists)
        if(currentLogoIndex>0) allLogos[currentLogoIndex - 1].style.color = "blue"
        // increment index
        currentLogoIndex++
        
    }, 1000); </script>
```

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted, but how do i loop this? i mean like when it turn red, and white all logos it will start turning it red, and white once again

Comment: You can just reset the index in the if statement instead of clearing the interval. I'll update the code above

Answer (score 0):

The looping effect you want can be achieved by adding and removing the a class (eg. active) using `el.classList.add()` and `el.classList.remove()` methods in an interval.

Solution

```js
  const logos = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".logos .logo"));
      let currentIndex = 0;

      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (currentIndex >= logos.length) {
          currentIndex = 0;
        }
        logos.forEach((x) => x.classList.remove("active"));

        logos[currentIndex].classList.add("active");
        currentIndex++;
      }, 1200);
```

```css
      .logos {
        display: flex;
        gap: 1rem;
      }
      .logos .logo {
        padding: 1rem;
        background-color: gainsboro;
        border-radius: 4px;
        transition: background-color 600ms ease-in-out;
      }
      .logos .logo.active {
        background-color: red;
      }
```

```html
   <div class="logos">
      <div class="logo">A</div>
      <div class="logo">B</div>
      <div class="logo">C</div>
      <div class="logo">D</div>
      <div class="logo">E</div>
    </div>
```